# What is wrong in this <div style="position: absolute HTML code?

Tags: html, css-position

What am I doing wrong in this HTML code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 100px; width: 1px; height: 1px; color: red;"></div> 
   </body>
   </html>
```

I was given it here about an hour ago, but it doesn't work - I don't see a red pixel in my "MS FrontPage" editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `background-color: red` instead of `color: red`. Voila... a red pixel!

Comment: clearly my brain isn't awake yet. I spent 5 min looking at that code and couldn't work it out.